# Executing a Batch file on a Azure Virtual Machine from outside the VM

Tags: windows, command-line, virtual-machine, batch, azure

I have an Azure VM running Windows 2016 Datacentre with a programme developed in R and RMarkdown. I can run the R script from the command line on the virtual machine (rather than from within the R/RStudio environment), and so therefore have I have a created a batch file with said command.

I now want to run this batch file on a schedule or from a trigger from outside the VM. How can I do this? From my Azure portal I've tried Azure Functions and Azure Logic Apps but I have not found a straightforward way to run the script.

Any help/advice greatly appreciated? Many thanks.

Comment: You can get more help in StackOverflow and ServerFault.

Comment: [Do not cross-post questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/271445). Instead, use a custom flag to ask a moderator to migrate your question to the correct site.

Comment: This is not on-topic at Stack Overflow @Biswapriyo

Comment: Agreed, this is not on-topic for StackOverflow. I think this is on-topic for both ServerFault and SuperUser, depending on the kinds of answer OP wants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try the Azure Custom Script Extension?
You can read more details in the following posts:

[Using Azure Custom Script Extension to execute scripts on Azure VMs](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/stefan_stranger/2017/07/31/using-azure-custom-script-extension-to-execute-scripts-on-azure-vms/)

[Custom Script Extension for Windows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows)